# How should i get missing value from two 2D array in php

Tags: php, laravel

I have two array

```
$a1 = Array
            (
            [0] => Array
                (
                [value] => 70,
                [unit] => kilogram(kg),
                [status] => active
            ),
            [1] => Array
                (
                [value] => 80,
                [unit] => kilogram(kg),
                [status] => inactive
            ),
            [2] => Array
                (
                [value] => 67,
                [unit] => gram(g),
                [status] => active
            ),
            [3] => Array
                (
                [value] => 54,
                [unit] => gram(g),
                [status] => inactive
            )
        );
```

And the second array is:

```
$a2 = Array
        (
        [0] => Array
            (
            [value] => 70,
            [unit] => kilogram(kg),
            [status] => active
        ),
        [1] => Array
            (
            [value] => 80,
            [unit] => kilogram(kg),
            [status] => inactive
        ),
        [2] => Array
            (
            [value] => 67,
            [unit] => gram(g),
            [status] => active
        ),
        [3] => Array
            (
            [value] => 54,
            [unit] => gram(g),
            [status] => inactive
        ),
        [4] => Array
            (
            [value] => 50,
            [unit] => kilogram(kg),
            [status] => active
        )
    );
```

What I want is to get the difference between the two arrays. i.e missing values from an array.

I used array_diff but it returns an error of :

> array to string conversion on array_diff line

Anyone have any solution.

Comment: Without the `array_diff` function call how can we help? Also is this actually how you created `$a2` and `$a1`? Seems strange to manually increment an array.

Comment: Do you want to check field `value` in given array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
{
    if ($key1 == $key2)
        return 0;
    else if ($key1 > $key2)
        return 1;
    else
        return -1;
}
$aDiff = array_diff_ukey($a1, $a2, 'key_compare_func');
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-ukey.php

Answer (score 0):

There would be many ways to achieve this , here is one of them, I assume you want to check field `value` in given array.

```
$arr1 = [["value" => 70,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"],["value" => 71,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"],["value" => 72,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"]];
$arr2 = [["value" => 70,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"],["value" => 72,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"],["value" => 73,"unit" => "kilogram(kg)","status" => "active"]];
$arr1Values = array_column($arr1,'value');
$arr2Values = array_column($arr2,'value');
$diff1 = array_diff($arr1Values,$arr2Values);
if(count($diff1)){
    echo "Extra in Arr 1\n";
    foreach($diff1 as $key=>$val){
        print_r($arr1[$key]);
    }
}
$diff2 = array_diff($arr2Values,$arr1Values);
if(count($diff2)){
    echo "Extra in Arr 2\n";
    foreach($diff2 as $key=>$val){
        print_r($arr2[$key]);
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d95900d01b44c06f2d16d9484d9b8cacbcae95c6)

Output:

```
Extra in Arr 2
Array
(
    [value] => 73
    [unit] => kilogram(kg)
    [status] => active
)
```

If you want keep all 3 element as combined unique then you can use below code

```
function func1($d){
    return implode(",",$d);//You can put any symbol here
};
$arr1Values = array_map('func1',$arr1);
$arr2Values = array_map('func1',$arr2);

$arr2ValuesDiff = array_diff($arr2Values,$arr1Values);
foreach($arr2ValuesDiff as $k=>$v){
    print_r(explode(',',$v));
}
```

[Live Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e81088f030d6a4e7c6fc8ab8329fee2ec31fd85b)

Comment: What if the `value` elements are the same?

Comment: @Nick: Although it is not specified but only value is unique, other two `unit`, `status` may be belongs to many.

Comment: @Nick:: And here `missing values from an array` values means field `value`

Comment: No, that means the array with the 3 elements in it.

Comment: @Nick: I am not sure about only field `value` as well you also not sure about `all 3 elements`. so lets check with OP

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code:

```
<?php
function arrayRecursiveDiff($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if(array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if(is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if(count($aRecursiveDiff)) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff;
        }
      }
      else {
        if($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    }
    else {
      $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
    }
  }

  return $aReturn;
}

$a1 = [
        ["value" => 70, "unit" => "kilogram(kg)", "status" => "active"],
        ["value" => 80, "unit" => "kilogram(kg)", "status" => "inactive"],
        ["value" => 67, "unit" => "gram(g)", "status" => "active"],
        ["value" => 54, "unit" => "gram(g)", "status" => "inactive"]
      ];

$a2 = [
        ["value" => 70, "unit" => "kilogram(kg)", "status" => "active"],
        ["value" => 80, "unit" => "kilogram(kg)", "status" => "inactive"],
        ["value" => 67, "unit" => "gram(g)", "status" => "active"],
        ["value" => 54, "unit" => "gram(g)", "status" => "inactive"],
        ["value" => 50, "unit" => "kilogram(kg)", "status" => "active"]
      ];

$arrdiff = arrayRecursiveDiff($a2, $a1);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arrdiff);
?>
```

Hope this may help you.

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff

Comment: If you are going to copy code from elsewhere, please attribute it. This is an exact copy of code posted as a comment on the PHP `array_diff` [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff).

Comment: Done. Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff